# Como fazer uma tabela dinâmica em um dataframe Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Boa tarde.
Estou migrando algumas atividades do excel para o python (ambiente que ainda sou leigo), e me deparei com um problema em fazer uma tabela dinâmica. Tentei usar o pivot_table mas não consegui obter o resultado que queria.

Basicamente estou lendo um csv de 2 colunas (que obtenho em outro código) e quero fazer uma tabela dinâmica nas duas colunas e criar uma terceira, gerando um novo dataframe.

O arquivo csv tem as colunas "VLAN" e "Interface". Quero colocar em 1 coluna todas as aparições únicas de VLANS associadas a sua Interface (coluna 2), na terceira coluna quantas aparições foram encontradas.
link csv: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OqbqcU5lidRtvL73cptct-oj4CMYNrhp

Trecho do csv (contem 700 linhas):

```
Interface   VLAN 
xe-0/0/0:2  2690 
xe-0/1/2    2691
xe-0/0/0:2  2690
xe-0/0/0:2  2690
xe-0/1/2    2691
```

Eu consigo contar as aparições separadas de VLAN e Interface, mas não juntas.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("MCO.csv",sep=";")
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df["VLAN"].value_counts())
print(df["Interface"].value_counts())
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df,index="VLAN")
print(df2)
```

output do erro na linha da pivot_table:

```
raise DataError("No numeric types to aggregate") pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

O resultado final que quero chegar seria esse dataframe:

```
VLAN    Interface   Contagem_VLAN
2689    xe-0/0/0:2  173
2690    xe-0/0/0:2  287
2691    xe-0/1/2    315
```

---

**Edit 1:**
Consegui resolver da maneira abaixo, mas não me parece muito inteligente.
Criei uma coluna de apoio só com "1" para poder fazer a soma, não sei se realmente isto é necessário.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv("MCO.csv",sep=";")
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.astype(str)

coluna_1 = pd.Series(1,index=np.arange(len(df)))
df.insert(loc=2,column="coluna_1",value=coluna_1)
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["VLAN","Interface"], aggfunc="sum")
print(df2)
```

output:

```
                 coluna_1
VLAN Interface           
2689 xe-0/0/0:2       173
2690 xe-0/0/0:2       287
2691 xe-0/1/2         315
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegues efetuar essa contagem através de um `groupby`:

```
df.groupby(['VLAN','Interface']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'contagem'})
```

Comment: Nossa, extremamente mais simples. Dei tanta volta pra chegar em algo parecido.
Muito obrigado drec4s.
Ainda estou sem reputação para votar, mas essa linha resolveu meu problema.